# Evaluate $\int_0^9 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this defined integral:

> $$\int_0^9 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I tried to solve by parts, so:

$$f(x)g(x) = \int f'(x)g(x)dx$$

where:

$$f(x) = \ln(x)$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$g(x) = 2\sqrt{x}$$

And I get:

$$\ln(x)2\sqrt x - \int\frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(x^m)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: You should use the substitution $x=u^2$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using by parts actually gives you:

$$2\sqrt{(x)}\ln(x)-2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x)}}dx$$
It's then fairly straightforward.

Comment: You need to enclose the argument of the radical in braces, not parentheses. (In fact, in the present case, since it's just one letter, you don't need to enclose it at all.)

Comment: Noted. Was in a hurry.

Comment: Right, I used the $g'(x)$ instead of $g(x)$ but I get $2\int\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$

Comment: That's right! @ChristianGiupponi

Answer (score 0):

Let $u(x)=\ln(x),v'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$.

$$\int_a^9 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt x}dx=\int_a^9 u(x)v'(x)dx=[u(x)v(x)]_a^9-\int_a^9u'(x)v(x)dx$$

$u'(x)=\frac{1}{x},v(x)=2\sqrt x$.

$$\begin{align}\int_a^9 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt x}dx&=[\ln(x)2\sqrt x]_a^9-\int_a^9\frac{2\sqrt x}{x}dx\\&=\ln(9)2\sqrt9-\ln(a)2\sqrt a -4\int_a^9\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}dx\\&=\ln(9)2\sqrt9-\ln(a)2\sqrt a -4\sqrt 9+4\sqrt a \end{align} $$

When you make tend $a$ to $0$, you have : $$\int_0^9 \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt x}dx=\ln(9)2\sqrt9-0 -4\sqrt 9+0=2\sqrt 9(\ln9-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=2\frac{ln(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$ now put $\sqrt{x}=u$ so integral becomes $4.ln(u).du$ which can easily be integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
\begin{equation}
I(a) = \int\limits_{0}^{b} x^{a} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\bigg|_{0}^{b} = \frac{b^{a+1}}{a+1}
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{b} x^{a} \mathrm{ln}(x) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\partial I(a)}{\partial a} = 
\frac{b^{a+1}}{(a+1)^{2}}[(a+1)\mathrm{ln}(b) - 1]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{b} \frac{\mathrm{ln}(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x & = 
\lim_{a \to -\frac{-1}{2}} \int\limits_{0}^{b} x^{a} \mathrm{ln}(x) \mathrm{d} x \\
& = \lim_{a \to -\frac{-1}{2}} \frac{b^{a+1}}{(a+1)^{2}}[(a+1)\mathrm{ln}(b) - 1] \\
& = 4\sqrt{b}[\mathrm{ln}(\sqrt{b})-1]
\end{align}

For $b=9$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{9} \frac{\mathrm{ln}(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x
= 4\sqrt{9}[\mathrm{ln}(\sqrt{9})-1]
= 12(\mathrm{ln}3-1)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

: Let $u=\ln x \,\,\And\,\,  {{e}^{u}}=x\Leftrightarrow du=\frac{dx}{x}\Leftrightarrow {{e}^{u}}du=dx$ ,then

$\int_{0}^{9}{\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\int_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}{\frac{u{{e}^{u}}du}{\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}}}=\int_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}{u{{e}^{u\left( 1-1/2 \right)}}du}=\int_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}{u\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}du}$

Let $U=u\,\,\And \,\,dV=\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}du\Leftrightarrow dU=du\,\,\And \,\,V=2\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}$then

$\int_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}{u\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}}du=\left[ 2u\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}} \right]_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}-2\int_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}{\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}du=\left[ 2u\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}-4\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}} \right]_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}=\left[ \sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}\left( 2u-4 \right) \right]_{-\infty }^{\ln 9}}$

$\therefore \int_{0}^{9}{\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}dx}=\underset{u\to -\infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\left( \sqrt{{{e}^{\ln 9}}}\left( 2\ln 9-4 \right)-\sqrt{{{e}^{u}}}\left( 2u-4 \right) \right)=\left( 3\left( 4\ln 3-4 \right) \right)=12\left( \ln 3-1 \right)$